# DDL for catalog_product_entity_varchar_tmp_indexer

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm doing some testing with Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.1 and am having trouble getting the DDL for catalog_product_entity_varchar_tmp_indexer, which appears to be a temporary table. Can someone help me find the DDL for it?

Comment: If you are using EE then you presumably have EE support from Magento - they will be able to provide you with a DB schema